# State_Selected is not working although state_pressed works

Tags: android, listview, textview

i have a problem. First check my code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/clickedtext" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/clickedtext" />
    <item  android:color="@color/defaulttext" />
</selector>
```

Here, defaulttext color appears at default state. When i clicked, text color in the listitem changes. But color of the text does not change when an item selected.

I tried some stuff, but i cannot handle this problem.
What should i do ?

Comment: what happens in the Java part? Do you call setSelected(true) on your view?

Comment: i use it on ListView, is it needed to use at textview too ?

Comment: There are some issues with `state_selected` on certain devices. You might have a look here for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237978/listview-item-state-selected-is-lost-on-samsung-device

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was also searching for an answer for this when using a ListView, and had to trawl through a lot of posts here before finding [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729579/1346778) which I believe is the best option, and worked like a charm.

The idea is to set the view as checked, and then use `state_activated` rather than `state_selected` to perform your selection. If you're using a ListView or similar you'll also need to call `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` to make sure only one item is checked. See [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729579/1346778) for more info

I hope this helps someone find the solution faster than I did!

Comment: Thanks, that answer is really useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729517/showing-the-current-selection-in-a-listview/9729579#9729579

Comment: @sleeke 
**The idea is to set the view as checked**  can you please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

when using a custom listitem-layout: set

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

as background